# export database to sdcard

Tags: android, sqlite

i need your help, i finish codding an application, but the problem is that database is inside the system:  /data/data/your.package.name , i am trying to have access to this database through Sdcard, i already look for solutions in this forum, there are plenty but i don't know how to make it work, for example :

```
         private class ExportDatabaseFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);

    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       this.dialog.setMessage("Exporting database...");
       this.dialog.show();
    }

    // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

       File dbFile =
                new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/com.mypkg/databases/mydbfile.db");

       File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
       if (!exportDir.exists()) {
          exportDir.mkdirs();
       }
       File file = new File(exportDir, dbFile.getName());

       try {
          file.createNewFile();
          this.copyFile(dbFile, file);
          return true;
       } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e("mypck", e.getMessage(), e);
          return false;
       }
    }

    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
       if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
          this.dialog.dismiss();
       }
       if (success) {
          Toast.makeText(ctx, "Export successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } else {
          Toast.makeText(ctx, "Export failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }

    void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
       FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
       FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
       try {
          inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
       } finally {
          if (inChannel != null)
             inChannel.close();
          if (outChannel != null)
             outChannel.close();
       }
    }

 }
```

Comment: is this a class that should i add to others ? and how is executed ??

Comment: Have it as a private class inside your activity class. Create an instance: ExportDatabaseFileTask task = new ExportDatabaseFileTask(). Execute it: task.execute.

Comment: thanks a lot for responding, whish class ?? the main ? or database adapter???

Comment: In whichever Activity you want to do this from. Add it inside the Activity class definition (i.e. at the same level as onCreate(), onPause() etc). Then create an instance and execute at the appropriate point, e.g. on a button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may helpful to you.

```
File f=new File("/data/data/YOURAPPPACKAGENAME/databases/YOURDATABASENAME");
                       FileInputStream fis=null;
                     FileOutputStream fos=null;

                    try
                    {
                      fis=new FileInputStream(f);
                      fos=new FileOutputStream("YOURSDCARDFOLDERPATH"+"/YOUREXPORTDDATBASENAME");
                      while(true)
                      {
                        int i=fis.read();
                        if(i!=-1)
                        {fos.write(i);}
                        else
                        {break;}
                      }
                      fos.flush();
                      Toast.makeText(ctx, "DB dump OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      Toast.makeText(ctx, "DB dump ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                      try
                      {
                        fos.close();
                        fis.close();
                      }
                      catch(Exception ioe)
                      {}
                    }
```

You must add sdcard read and write permission into your manifest.xml file and after database successfully exported you can pull this database using DDMS tools into your computer and open using SQLite Manager.

Comment: as i told you before the problem is not about the code, it is everywhere, but how to use it , for example where to put this code in which activity, that is my issue. thanks friend for your efforts :)

Comment: You just directly put this code into your button click listner event onclick() and/or if you want to implement this into AsyncTask then you can put this code into InBackground(). It's very easy.

Comment: i am very grateful for your contribution, i thought that is more complicated than that, thanks.

Comment: it works, i have the file in Sdcard, but i don't have data ? i don't know why ?

Comment: i mean the rows that i entered to database

Comment: check if your database file size>0 then you can get data into database.

Comment: i have the file, when i open it with sqlite manager i found empty rows, and i am sure that i entered data to database ??? help please

Comment: wait please tell me your all procedure what you actually want?

Comment: well i have questions which answers go to database, i need to have access to this database from sdcard, with your method i get the file, but when i open it i don't have information that i entered, it is an empty file with no data, if you have an idea tell me ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43833/discussion-between-manish-patel-and-utman-alami)